# Is a purely Electron or Proton bomb possible?

Tags: electrons, protons

Since electrons repel other electrons and protons repel other protons, if you had enough of either of these in an enclosed space, and suddenly removed the enclosing barrier, would the repelling force between the particles release enough energy to cause significant effect? How many particles would need to be present to equate to a regular stick of dynamite?

Comment: See [Coulomb Explosion](https://www.nature.com/articles/nchem.2161)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Proton-Proton Bombs

Protons repel each other electromagnetically, but that repulsion is weaker than the strong force attraction between protons at short distances, so the focus is on reducing the total binding energy of a nucleus in the end state relative to the starting state via nuclear fission or nuclear fusion. A proton-proton bomb is basically an A-bomb like the one used in Hiroshima and Nagasaki (or a later H-bomb). The first A-bomb used in anger called "Little Man" weighed 9700 pounds of which 140 pounds was warhead, and had a yield equal to 60,000,000 sticks of TNT (which have half a pound of TNT each).

An A-bomb which relies on nuclear fission of atoms like uranium (with 92 protons) and plutonium (with 94 protons) isn't a truly pure example of a proton-proton bomb because these isotypes also have lots of neutrons that contribute to the binding energy.

A more pure example would be an H-bomb which fuses hydrogen-1 atoms (basically protons with an electron around them) with an igniting detonator into helium. This is quite doable technologically as an uncontrolled one time reaction, even though doing so efficiently on a sustained basis in a controlled manner to generate energy for practical energy production is not currently technologically feasible.

The yield of an H-bomb is even greater per pound of warhead mass than an A-bomb, although basically similar at a gross order of magnitude level. [For example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W47):

> The W47 [thermonuclear warhead] was 18 in (460 mm) in diameter and 47
> in (1,200 mm) long, and weighed 720 lb (330 kg) in the Y1 model and
> 733 lb (332 kg) in the Y2 model. The Y1 model had design yield of 600
> kilotons and the Y2 model had a doubled design yield of 1.2 megatons.

The Y2 was equivalent to 4,800,000,000 sticks of dynamite from a 733 pound bomb warhead.

## Electron-Electron Bombs

The problem with an "electron-electron" bomb is containing the electrons prior to the bomb being used arriving at its target. You would need some sort of magnetic containment field, which would take heavy materials to generate, and would leak due to quantum tunneling (the leaking would get worse at the electrons were packed more tightly). Also, electrons packed into each other would tend to collide and produce new particles much like they would in a particle accelerator. The explosive force upon releasing the electrons would depend both upon how tightly the electrons were packed and upon their kinetic energy within the containment area.

So, the explosive force would depend very much upon the design of the bomb, and it might not be feasible at all as a weapon.

A more fruitful and conventional approach to an electron weapon would be to shoot a stream of very fast moving electrons towards a target like a ray gun. This is what happens inside an old school CRT screen but at a non-weaponized energy scale.

Comment: Given that the di-proton ($^{2}$He) is unstable, I really don't see how this is correct at all.

Comment: @JonCuster A real world "proton-proton" bomb usually involves uranium (atomic number 92), plutonium (atomic number 94) or hydrogen (atomic number 1 with no neutrons). Neutrons in the larger nuclei can be thought of as part of the structure containing the protons in the bomb, even though it isn't that simple because both neutrons and protons contribute to nuclear binding energy (an H-bomb is a more pure example). The relationship between nuclear binding energy and the number of nucleons in an atom is not linear. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Nuclear_binding_energy_curve

Comment: @JonCuster The answer is a bit askew from the question mostly because the question implicitly assumes (incorrectly) that the primary source of explosive energy in a bunch of tightly packed protons comes from the electromagnetic force rather than the strong force.

Comment: Well, no, if one did try to force a bunch of protons together, one would have quite an electrostatic force to overcome (or else fusion would be much easier). The fact that an attempt to put two protons close together in a 'nucleus' is tremendously unstable and comes flying back apart as protons indicates this. Trying to suggest that neutrons are just 'part of the structure' glosses over the actual nuclear physics to an amazing extent.

Comment: @JonCuster Also, while the di-proton stability isn't itself relevant, the whole point of a bomb is to have something that hovers between stability and instability. You want it to be stable until you set it off, then you want it to be unstable and exothermic when the time comes to blow something up.

Comment: No, the fact that the di-proton is not stable shows immediately that you cannot just compress a bunch of protons into a 'nucleus' - nuclear physics is giving you a big sign there.

Comment: "if one did try to force a bunch of protons together, one would have quite an electrostatic force to overcome (or else fusion would be much easier)." This is exactly what happens when an H-bomb is detonated and it is very technologically feasible. Uncontrolled fusion in a bomb isn't all that hard to produce. What makes nuclear fusion power hard technologically is producing a sustained and controlled nuclear fusion reaction in a manner efficient enough to generate net usable energy.

Comment: 2 major points on an 'H-bomb' that you miss. First, the fusion that occurs is D-T fusion, which is much easier than any other fusion reaction for very good nuclear physics reasons. Second, the entire purpose of said fusion reaction is not to produce energy, per se, but to make a bunch of neutrons to kick start the primary or secondary, since fissioning U/Pu releases 10x the energy of D-T fusion.

Comment: @JonCuster I agree that even a thermonuclear bomb is not a pure proton-proton bomb of the type hypothesized, but it is pretty much as close as is possible to get to one in real life.

Comment: @ohwilleke The answer is interesting, but it leaves open whether it could be possible to balance the strong force attraction and the electrostatic repulsion between a whole bunch of protons (perhaps in the form of neutron-free He nuclei subjected to some kind of external regulation) until some triggering mechanism tipped the balance in favor of repulsion, whereupon the whole electrostatic potential would run away explosively.

Comment: PS: Sorry. I forgot that even if the forces in each nucleus were balanced, there would still be extreme electric forces between the nuclei, and between the ensemble and the environment... I am no physics expert. I just wanted to see a more thorough consideration of the whole concept.